# innodb_file_per_table and ibdata files

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am looking at mysql installation (Version 5.7.19). The mysqld is running and has innodb_file_per_table set to on. Looking at the tables using a mysql client shows up that tables all have engine "InnoDB" set. There are files ibdata1 and ibdata2 in innodb_data_file_path and also the .ibd files. I wondering now since it was my newbee understanding that innodb_files_per_table obsoltes the ibdata* files? Am I wrong or is the presence of the .ibd files and ibdata* files at the same time an indication for a mis-configured database?

Comment: If you were hoping to shrink the disk space allocated to `ibdata*`, that is a different question.  (And it has been Asked and Answered many times.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ibdata1` stores InnoDB dictionary, undo segment(s), and doublewrite  buffer. So, `ibdata1` is needed regardless `innodb_file_per_table` setting.